# Asymptotic behaviour of Fourier transform: $|F[f]|=|\lambda^{-k}F[f^{(k)}]|$ for absolutely continuous $f$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's (p. 429 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that if function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ *is such that* $f^{(k-1)}$ [the $(k-1)$-th order derivative] on any finite interval and if $f,...,f^{(k)}\in L_1(-\infty,\infty)$ [i.e. they are Lebesgue-summable on $\mathbb{R}$], then$$F[f^{(k)}]=(i\lambda)^k F[f]$$where $F[f]$ is the Fourier transform defined by $F[f](\lambda)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)e^{-i\lambda t}d\mu_t$, where $\mu_t$ is the linear Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know, from the proof given in the same page, that such an equality holds for $k=1$ (lemma (3)). **Provided that** $f$ is absolutely continuous on any finite interval, induction guarantees that $F[f^{(k)}]=(i\lambda)^k F[f]$, as far as I understand. I do not think we may drop the hypothesis of the absolutely continuity of $f$.

Then the book, talking as if such a statement held in general, in another lemma bearing another number, (4), says that if $f^{(k)}\in L_1(-\infty,\infty)$ then $$\lim_{|\lambda|\to\infty}|F[f]|=\lim_{|\lambda|\to\infty}\frac{|F[f^{(k)}]|}{|\lambda|^k}=0.$$I think it is still **intended that** $f,...,f^{(k-1)}\in L_1(-\infty,\infty)$ and $f$ is absolutely continuous on any finite interval: am I right? I do not think that the hypothesis may be dropped.

This asymptotic estimate is then used to prove the following lemma (5), which says that *if $f''$ exists and belongs to $L_1(-\infty, \infty)$, then $F[f]$ is* [Lebesgue] *absolutely integrable*, but, again, I think that we must consider it **under the hypothesis** that $f$ is absolutely continuous on any finite interval and $f,f'\in L_1(-\infty,\infty)$. Is not that so? I should admit that this much celebrated textbook is not so easy for me to do exegesis on...
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asymptotic estimate $|F[f](\lambda)|\to 0$ holds under much weaker conditions. I can't read Kolmogorov-Fomin, so I don't know what they're claiming, but here's a proof assuming only that $f$ is in $L^1(-\infty,\infty)$.

The idea is to approximate $f$. First, we know how to show that $F[g'](\lambda) = i\lambda F[g](\lambda)$ if $g$ is $C^\infty$ and compactly supported. So for $g\in C_c^\infty$ we have

$$
|F[g](\lambda)| = \frac{|F[g'](\lambda)|}{|\lambda|}\to 0
$$
as $\lambda\to\infty$.

Since $C_c^\infty$ is dense in $L^1$ (w.r.t $L^1$-norm), given $\varepsilon>0$ we may find $g\in C_c^\infty$ with $\Vert f-g \Vert_{L^1}<\varepsilon$. Then
$$
\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}~dx\right| \leq \left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x)-g(x))e^{-i\lambda x}~dx\right| + \left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)e^{-i\lambda x}~dx\right|.
$$
So we have the bounds
$$
\left|F[f](\lambda)\right| \leq \Vert f-g \Vert_{L^1} + \left|F[g](\lambda)\right| < \varepsilon + \left|F[g](\lambda)\right|.
$$

As $|\lambda|\to\infty$ the second term goes to $0$, and since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary this shows that $|F[f](\lambda)|\to 0$ as $|\lambda|\to\infty$.

Now you can do this for any number of derivatives on $g$ since $g$ is compactly supported, which gives you many more asymptotic estimates in terms of $g$ and its derivatives. Notice that we did not even use the derivative of $f$ in this proof.

On the other hand the identity $i\lambda F[f](\lambda) = F[f'](\lambda)$ is of course going to need some more regularity on $f$ than just integrability.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I didn't know that $C^{\infty}_c$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. How can we prove that? I only know that polynomials are dense in $L^1[a,b]$... Thank you again!

Comment: There are a variety of ways. For example, finite linear combinations of step functions are dense, and you can approximate those via smooth functions. Or you might choose to rely on the theory of mollifiers. There are lots of useful dense subspaces of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ that are important to the theory.